# IntelliJ Idea 12 worksheet + sbt + Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have IntelliJ Idea 12 and sbt (as a plugin for IntelliJ also) installed. If I compile or run a Scala application in sbt, everything works fine. However, if I run it in a worksheet, then Idea will complain that `"object not found"` + object I import using `import` operator. Of course, it's added as a dependency and, as I said before, it will run successfully without errors if I run it in a terminal using:

```
sbt run
```

How do I make a worksheet work?

Comment: Did you add your dependencies in the `build.sbt` file? If so then did you also re-run the `sbt gen-idea` so that IntelliJ knows about the new dependencies?

Comment: @maba now it says "Failed to initialize compiler: class scala.reflect.BeanInfo not found."